# How to check the class represented by Element is sub type of specified class during annotation processing?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing

I have a data class

```
@SomeAnnotation
data class Foo(
    @SerializedName("str")
    val stringValue: String = "",
    @SerializedName("int")
    val intValue: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("list")
    val listValue: List<Long> = listOf()
)
```

during annotation processing, I can not check if Foo class's fields is `kotlin.collections.Collections` (like List, Set)

My Annotation Processor like this:

```
class SomeAnnotationProcessor: AbstractProcessor() {
    fun processSomeAnnotation(clazz: Element) {
        clazz.enclosedElements.asSequence().filter {
            it.kind == ElementKind.FIELD && !it.modifiers.contains(Modifier.STATIC)
        }.map {
            // how to check if the fields' of clazz is Collections?
            // I just know how to obtain parameterize type of this field like this
            (it as Symbol).type.typeArguments
        }.toList()
    }
}
```

Is this any way to check if all fields of an Element is sub type of specified class like `kotlin.collections.Collections`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In java I use this

```
/**
   * Checks if the element type is assignable of the target class (i.e. if it's a derivative type of
   * it)
   *
   * @param element the element
   * @param targetClass the target class
   * @return true if the element is assignable from the target class, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean isAssignableFrom(Element element, Class<?> targetClass) {
    return isAssignableFrom(element.asType(), targetClass);
  }

  /**
   * Checks if the type mirror is assignable of the target class (i.e. if it's a derivative type of
   * it)
   *
   * @param typeMirror the type mirror
   * @param targetClass the target class
   * @return true if the type mirror is assignable from the target class, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean isAssignableFrom(TypeMirror typeMirror, Class<?> targetClass) {
    return types.isAssignable(
        typeMirror, types.getDeclaredType(elements.getTypeElement(targetClass.getCanonicalName())));
  }
```

where types is `javax.lang.model.util.Types` and and elements is `javax.lang.model.util.Elements` that both can be obtained from the `ProcessingEnvironment`